# Postgres and Atlassian Jira: driver issue

Tags: postgresql, jira

I am trying to setup a server with centOS 32 bit to install Atlassian Jira on it.
I followed the official Atlassian installation guide at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Installing+JIRA

Now I am running the Setup Wizard and I need to configure a PostgreSQL database. On my centOS, I installed version 8.4.20 via yum.
However, I am having a hard time setting Jira. Postgres is running and I can login via Linux console, but when I test the connection to the database, I get the following error:

```
Error connecting to database
Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
Connection refused
```

Also, this error appears when I type the full public IP address. If I insert localhost, I get this:

```
Error connecting to database
FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "jiradbuser"
```

If I insert

```
http://<public ip>
```

I get the following:

```
Error connecting to database
No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://http://<public ip>:5432/jiradb
```

However, I put my jdbc driver into /opt/atlassian/jira/lib and its name is postgresql-8.4-703.jdbc4.jar. Postgresql version is 8.4.20.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why use such an obsolete version of PostgreSQL? For a new install surely you should be using 9.3. If JIRA specifies that you must use 8.4 then they need to get with this decade.

Comment: I am using that version because it is what I got installed with the command yum install postgresql-server. I'd be happy to switch to a newer version.

Comment: Ah, so you're on an old operating system, maybe RHEL6 / CentOS 6. In that case, see http://yum.postgresql.org/ . Don't start a new deployment with an old PostgreSQL. (that isn't the problem you're having, though).

Comment: `jdbc:postgresql://http://<public ip>:5432/jiradb` needs to be `jdbc:postgresql://<public ip>:5432/jiradb`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It looks like it was, then manu changed it after the ident error, rather than dealing with the config issue server side.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't notice the weird driver path at the first time, so I just reported that additional error case. Thanks for you contribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

By default, PostgreSQL listens only on the local loopback interface, so connecting to the public IP won't work. If you're connecting from localhost you don't need to anyway, just use `localhost`.

> FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "jiradbuser"

This is good, it shows that you're connecting to PostgreSQL successfully, then getting an authentication error when trying to log in.

Your PostgreSQL server install defaulted to `ident` authentication for TCP/IP connections, but the JIRA application isn't running under a unix user named "jiradbuser" so the connection is rejected. Change `pg_hba.conf` to use `md5` instead of `ident` and set a password for the user. See [the client authentication chapter in the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html), particularly, [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://http://:5432/jiradb

I have no idea where you got the idea that that URL would work...

You want something like:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jiradb
```

Comment: concerning the loopback, I tried it and the error I get is the one about the driver. Concerning your second point, I set up the pg_hba.conf as you say. Concerning the third point, it was a matter of copy and paste (both in the configuration and in the thread).

Comment: @Manu If you changed to `md5` in pg_hba.conf then you most likely forgot to restart/reload PostgreSQL afterwards, or you mucked up the config change. If in doubt, show your full `pg_hba.conf` in an edit to the question.

Comment: @Manu, it's unclear from your response as to what exactly you copy and pasted (was the C+P error just on SO, or in your config too?). As Craig wrote, there should be no "http://" anywhere in your JDBC string. If you're getting an error about no suitable driver found, then it means that your JDBC string is improperly formatted. Can you post the exact JDBC string that you used when trying to use the loopback interface? (Or a screenshot of the inputs you're providing to the installer?)

Comment: @ScottDudley It was a copy and paste on StackOverflow and, at the same time, in the configuration.

Comment: @CraigRinger I hadn't restarted the server! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I could solve it setting up the postgres driver .jar from maven repository to \target\jira\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late to the question here but thought I'd add a couple bits to help out the future, going backwards:

**No suitable driver found for jdbc**

```
    A while ago Atlassian didn't distribute the PostGreSQL JDBC driver file with the JIRA releases. They have been doing this for a while now (I'd say since mid 2013) - regardless, the driver file belongs in the <jira-base>/lib directory unless you are doing a WAR install, in which case you shouldn't, and just put the driver file in the lib directory anyway
```

**FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "jiradbuser"**

```
1. Listen on a socket if you need to - The best approach to this is to look at your JDBC driver URL - if it has an IP/hostname other than 127.x.x.x or 'localhost' you need to modify PostGreSQL to listen to a TCP port by modifying your postgresql.conf file to enable listening on ports. Just find the file, back it up, then open it and search for localhost, read the file comments and make the correct change. If you find yourself looking around in multiple locations in the file or changing more than a single word you are trying too hard - restore your backup and try again. Just remember to *stop* and *start* your postgres db cluster when you are done

2. enable the correct login METHOD in pg_hba.conf (same directory as the postgresql.conf file - on unix typically under /etc/postgresql/<version>/main/.) - this is difficult to writeup in brief but I'll try
    1. backup the pg_hba.conf file - I ain't foolin, this is something you'll be happy with later - back the sucker up
    2. edit the file 
    3. go to the bottom of the file - look for the last line like "# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD"
    4. comment out every line under this 'table heading' line
        - the reason to do this is that the package maintainers often fall back to commenting here and so you'll have 2 commented out lines and then one line that isn't commented out - and you'll never notice it - it's easiest to just start off with commenting out the whole block of stuff so there isn't a single uncommented line in the file
        - add a two lines for the postgres user to connect local and to a db socket unless your corporate security does not allow - something like this:
        local   all             postgres        127.0.0.1/32     peer 
        host    all             postgres        127.0.0.1/32     trust
        - add a line for your jiradbuser to connect to the newly created database via sockets with md5 encryption. md5 isn't the best - there are other options to google - if you use md5, it'd look something like this:
        host    jiraversiondb   jiradbuser      127.0.0.1/32     md5
```

Then save the file, restart postgres cluster (with a stop and start, not with the 'restart' option), and test connecting from the command line.

**How to test connections from the command line**

If you are logged into a unix system with the postgres tools installed you should be able to mimic the connection attempt which the JIRA server will try to connect to the database. If you cannot connect to the new postgresql db from the command line it's a REAL GOOD chance that JIRA won't be able to either. Plus you'll get better error messages. So to do this just bring up a shell and enter (replacing variables where appropriate - things within the '<' and '>' characters) - all the values for these are in your head and the postgresql.conf file:

```
psql --port <port - default is 5434> --username=<db user name> --password --dbname=<database name>
```

Once you can connect from the command line it's a good bet JIRA will as well - no promises, but you'll be on sound footing.

*...ahhh....now, that'll hopefully help someone...*